How to prevent "ghost objects" in a custom RenderEngine?
When implementing a custom rendering engine, the viewport will draw "ghost" versions of objects on its own.
This seems to only write the depth value of the model, independent of what i am about to draw in my renderer.
In fact, even the example provided here which doesn't draw any object suffers from this issue: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html#simple-render-engine
This is what it looks like in the view-port with nothing drawn:

You can see that it over-draws the grid and the lines for the empty object.
Note that this also happens with an inverted cube.
I originally noticed this with back-faces in my renderer, EEVEE does not have this behavior with back-faces.
Is there any way to disable this?

Isn't that just the viewport overlay, that you can disable with Shift+Alt+Z ? Or else I misunderstood your question. It will not appear if you try to render with F12.

The issue is not with the overlays you can see, but rather what you cannot see. In the example, the custom renderer is not drawing anything, yet blender still fills in the shape of the object (not the orange outline, the cube itself). So it will overwrite any gizmos like the axis and grid with it. This is something blender seems to do internally, but not in EEVEE
